# How can i query to get the multiple values in SimpleDB (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

[image: In that Picture i have colored one part. How can i query to get these values like double entry in Simple Db AWS]

[image]jpg

In that Picture  i have colored one part. i have attribute called "deviceModel". It contains more than one value.. i want to take using query from my domain which ItemName() contains deviceModel attribute values more than one value.

Thanks,

Senthil Raja

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct approach to get what you are asking.. You need to manipulate by writing your own piece of code. By running SELECT query you will get the item Attribute-value pair. So here you need to traverse each each itemName() and count values of your desire attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are refering to is called MultiValued Attributes.  When you put a value in the attribute - if you don't replace the existing attribute value the values will multiply, giving you an array of items connected to the value of that attribute name.

How you create them will depend on the sdk/language you are using for your REST calls, however look for the Replace=true/false when you set the attribute's value.

Here is the documentation page on retrieving them: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/ (look under Using Amazon SimpleDB -> Using Select to Create Amazon SimpleDB Queries -> Queries on Attributes with Multiple Values)

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for ur answer.. now am edited my question.. That is "i have attribute called "deviceModel". It contains more than one value.. i want to take using query from my domain which ItemName() contains deviceModel attribute values more than one value." Please help to resolve this...

Comment: There are 2 constructs used to query the multi-valued attributes:  Intersection and Every() - which allow you to deal with the individual attributes on an item otherwise your queries will return them all.  There isn't a way to retrieve which ones have currently have multiple values stored in them.